# Separating multiple items from user input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

I want my user to enter an arbitrarily long list of items and then separate them behind the scenes into a format that I can easily store in my database. I have two thoughts on how to do this, but only one that I can get to work (the less elegant version).

Thought 1 (this is the one I can get to work): Provide user with a `UITextView` and have them enter items separated by a special character, `;` for example. When they submit the form I parse it out with regex and then store accordingly. This is not as elegant from a UI/UX standpoint as I'd like, but I can make this one work.

Thought 2 (this is what I think would be better): Provide a `UITextField` with a `+` button by it. User enters 1 item and then clicks the `+` button to make another `UITextField` appear. If more than 1 textfield is on screen they each gain a `-` button to "delete" that field. Any ideas on how I could go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would do this with a UITableView, and insert a new row every time that they hit +.

Comment: Ah...so simple. I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Xcode template for master/detail on the iPhone.

It has a  table view into which you can add new rows by pressing the + button top right. In this case each row is a default tableViewCell, but you could easily modify to add a `UITextField`

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 sounds like it would be pretty easy with a UITableView. You could have a text field above it so that you do not have to show a new view to enter data. Then just clear the text field once they have entered the data. You could use swipe to delete on the table to delete entries.

```
/-----------------\
|Prompt text  | + |
|------------------
| User entry 1    |
| User entry 2    |
| User entry 3    |
| User entry 4    |
|                 |
\-----------------/
```

Another way to implement option 1 is [TITokenField](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField). It allows the user to type until they press the token delimeter key (',' by default I think). At this point a token is created based on the text the user entered.

There are various call backs that can be used with it, so that you can validate their input before the token is created. Processing the list of items the user entered is then as simple as iterating over an array of tokens. Bonus feature: TITokenField can work with data sources as an autocomplete. The demo app shows something very similar to what you are describing, with a plus button to add a new token. Tokens can be deleted by selecting them then pressing backspace.